# Why does the html5 image placeholder act as a Reset button?

Tags: asp.net, html, google-chrome, forms

In testing out the various HTML5 input types (button, checkbox, color, date, datetime, datetimelocal, email, file, hidden, image, month, number, password, radio, range, reset, search, submit, tel, text, time, url, week), everything works pretty much as I would expect except for three things:

1. if I click in the "image" placeholder (I haven't assigned an image to the image element), it acts as a Reset button - everything I've entered in prior elements is lost
2. When I select a color from the dialog using the color element, the color does not change - it starts black, and stays black
3. The datetime element acts like a generic text element - no datetime help is offered, as they are in the data and datetimelocal elements

I know that HTML5 isn't really "due" until 2020 or later, nevertheless I'm wondering if these anomalies are seen by others (tested using Chrome)

Interestingly, a text input element that I used for entering an email address prompted with my email address just as the email element did. What is the value-added part of the email element - that it will validate a correct email format?

If I have an actual image:

```
<input type="image" name="image1" id="Image1" width="210" height="140" src="FallFoliageAndWater.png" />
```

...it does the same thing: clicking on the image blanks out all the text I've entered in the other elements...???

### UPDATE

I reckon the reason the text element acts like an email element is because it's smart enough to see that it's own name is Email:

```
<p>
    <label for="Email"> Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="Email"/>
</p>
```

If I change the name and id to "[g,G]eezlebop":

```
<p>
    <label for="Geezlebop"> Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="geezlebop" id="Geezlebop"/>
</p>
```

...it reverts to being just a silly old text element, with no clue as to what it should hold.

Comment: As far as datetime, I believe it's up to each browser to implement helper GUI controls.  You can see Chrome lacks datetime support here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp

Comment: According to that site (anathema to Paul Irish, et al, BTW), the color element is supported by Chrome, and yet it exhibits the less-than-user-friendly behavior I mentioned above.